# SQlite Busy error in Windows Universal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have SQlite in my universal 8.1 app. When I run windows 8.1 app, It works great But when I run my windows phone app I get error SQlite busy.
It's my code:

```
private async void getSQLiteDataBase()
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;
        conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Setting.db");
        var ListIndex = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "ColorSettingIndex").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var AlertPercent = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "DataPlanAlertPercent").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var UpdateTimeIndex = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "UpdateTimeIndex").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var NotificationIsEnabled = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "NotificationIsEnabled").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var FirstNotification = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "FirstNotification").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var SecondNotification = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "SecondNotification").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var ThirdNotification = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "ThirdNotification").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var TilesIsEnabled = await conn.Table<SettingTable>().Where(x => x.Name == "TilesIsEnabled").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (ListIndex != null && AlertPercent != null && UpdateTimeIndex != null &&
            NotificationIsEnabled != null && FirstNotification != null 
            && SecondNotification != null && ThirdNotification != null && TilesIsEnabled != null)
        {
        ....
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to help me?
note: I searched before and I found that I have to close database But there is no property for close my database on Windows universal 8.1. I see example of SQlite on Windows and They don't have any code for close database.
I'm sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: Closing the database means calling `conn.Dispose()`

Comment: thanks for answer. I use SQLiteAsyncConnection so there is no dispose property But If I use SQLiteConnection I have dispose and close property. Is any difference between two this?

Comment: The `Dispose` method calls the `Close` method.

Comment: Ok But I use SQLiteAsyncConnection (not SQLiteConnection). there is no SQLiteAsyncConnection.dispose But we have SQLiteConnection.dispose.  so any defernce between this? http://blog.tpcware.com/2014/05/universal-app-with-sqlite-part-2/

Comment: thanks. I change and solve my problem.